# How to format following tabular content?

Tags: tables

I have some text like below and need to convert it to latex.

[image]

I used the following latex code to create it.

```
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{ cc} 

 PIXELS: &               \shortstack{ (00100111 11101001 11001000) \\
                                 (00100111 11001000 11001001) \\
                                 (11001000 00100111 11101001)  }\\ \\
 240: & 011110000 \\ \\
 RESULT: &               \shortstack{(00100110 11101001 11001001)\\
                                 (00100111 11001001 11001000)\\
                                 (11001000 00100110 11101000) }\\

\end{tabular}
\end{center}
```

but output is like this

[image]

I need some expert help to correct this format.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image]

```
\begin{tabular}{ lll} 

 PIXELS& : &              (00100111 11101001 11001000) \\
        &&                         (00100111 11001000 11001001) \\
         &&                        (11001000 00100111 11101001)  \\
 240&: & 011110000 \\ 
 RESULT&: &               (00100110 11101001 11001001)\\
         &&                        (00100111 11001001 11001000)\\
         &&                        (11001000 00100110 11101000) \\

\end{tabular}
```

to further reduce column space replace with

```
\begin{tabular}{ l@{}ll}
```

[image]

to add additional row spacing

```
\begin{tabular}{ l@{}ll} 

 PIXELS& : &              (00100111 11101001 11001000) \\
        &&                         (00100111 11001000 11001001) \\
         &&                        (11001000 00100111 11101001)  \\
         &&\\
 240&: & 011110000 \\
 &&\\ 
 RESULT&: &               (00100110 11101001 11001001)\\
         &&                        (00100111 11001001 11001000)\\
         &&                        (11001000 00100110 11101000) \\

\end{tabular}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you , it is working as expected. :)